# GWT Welcome Files for Multiple Modules

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, web.xml

What's the relationship between a GWT app's `web.xml` `<welcome-file-list>`, each module's `EntryPoint` and the `war/<myapp>/<myapp>.html` when an app has more than 1 module? Is there more than 1 `<welcome-file>`? In such a case, how do all three relate to each other?

Comment: I think `welcome-file-list` is related to the JSR specs. IMHO `welcome-file-list` is related to the server side, and usefull in such situations : https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome-file is what a server serves if no page is specified in a user request. For example, if a user enters in his browser www.your-domain.com/, then a welcome file is served. But if a user enters www.your-domain.com/MyModule.jsp - MyModule.jsp is served.

Modules typically have an entry point, but they don't have to. You may have modules which are inherited by other modules and don't have an entry point of their own. If a module does have an entry point, there should be a host page like MyModule.html or MyModule.jsp that loads MyModule.

Comment: what if there are more than one welcome-file elements in the welcome-file-list tag ?

Comment: The server will try each file on the list in the order specified, until it finds a file that exists in the directory that a user tries to access.

Comment: What if there are multiples files in the welcome-file-list like <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> And all the files are properly there in the project

Comment: As I said, it will choose the first that it finds.